# Google APIs: downloading and reading the sources

Tags: android

My goal is to understand every single bit of the following example:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager

I can run the example successfully, but now I want to understand every single
line of code in the example. For as far as the standard android APIs I can look
up their function by googling them up and looking at developer.android.com, but
for the other lines that come from the Google APIs I cannot find the up-to-date
1.6 sources on the web for clsses such as the following:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android2.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.clientlogin.ClientLogin;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.picasa.PicasaClient;
import com.google.api.services.picasa.PicasaUrl;
import com.google.api.services.picasa.model.AlbumEntry;
import com.google.api.services.picasa.model.UserFeed;
```

I cannot see any JavaDoc in eclipse, so the only alternative I have to learn about
these is to look at the code. How can I use mercurial to sign out up to date copies
of the Google APIs including those classes that can be used on android?

I think, since I cannot find what I want on the web is to grab the sources
as that seems to be the only way to learn what I need, but I don't know how
to use hg to do this, because I don't know how to use hg nor the site where
I can get the sources from.

Thank you for your help,

John Goche

Comment: You have to self understand by test it or run it no other alternative use google

Comment: But I would like to be able to check out the sources...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse the following post might be useful:

[Attaching Android platform source in Eclipse](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before and read through the previous answer on how to setup the build environment for Android. Unfortunately, the build environment so far does not support Windows Box. So a quick way is to download the source for a particular android version (e.g. 2.2) and extract to a local directory. In your Eclipse project, right click on android.jar to open the properties dialog. click on Java Source Attachment and enter the root directory of your source. Then refresh your project. You're set to debug through the source on Windows.